# How to split character using c++ win32 Api?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

i am using c++ win32 Api.

i want to split the character using `delimiter`.

that character like `"CN=USERS,OU=Marketing,DC=RAM,DC=COM"`.

i want to split the charcter into after the first comma(,).that means i need only

`OU=Marketing,DC=RAM,DC=COM.`

i already tried `strtok` function,but it split CN=USERS only.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c

Comment: Why do you need Win32 api for that?

Comment: @ Sidharth @ chris :I cant use string,Std::substring like that,only i can use windows functions,thats y,can u give any other suggestions.

Comment: Use `strchr` to find the first comma. You can then point a `char *` at that position, and there's your string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code, you should be able to get each item(separated by ',') easily:
strtok version:

```
char domain[] = "CN=USERS,OU=Marketing,DC=RAM,DC=COM";
  char *token = std::strtok(domain, ",");
  while (token != NULL) {
      std::cout << token << '\n';
      token = std::strtok(NULL, ",");
  }
```

std::stringstream version:

```
std::stringstream ss("CN=USERS,OU=Marketing,DC=RAM,DC=COM");
std::string item;
while(std::getline(ss, item, ',')) 
{
  cout << item << endl;
}
```

Have a look at std::getline()
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: @ billz :thanks for ur reply,but i cant use std::stringstream and etc.can u give other windows function like strtok,strcmp etc.

Comment: @sanju: strtok, strcmp are not windows functions. it's part of standard CRT (C runtime library)

Answer (score 1):

Using `strchr` makes it quite easy:

```
char domain[] = "CN=USERS,OU=Marketing,DC=RAM,DC=COM";
char *p = strchr(domain, ',');
if (p == NULL)
{
    // error, no comma in the string
}
++p; // point to the character after the comma
```